# Preencher URL de site externo com dados digitados

Tags: php, javascript, html

Preciso criar um código, em HTML mais simples possível, onde uma pessoa digita determinada string e clica em um botão.

Com isso, abre-se em uma nova aba uma URL com essa string nela(exemplo.com/string).

Estou começando a estudar agora e, por enquanto, consegui chegar somente nisso:

```html
<form>
  <label for="dadopesquisado">Digite aqui:</label>
  <input type="text"  id="texto" name="texto"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar">
</form>
```

Comment: *"Preciso criar um código"* e o que já conseguiu fazer? coloca na pergunta

Comment: Sou iniciante e consegui fazer somente isso rsrs

Comment: Você já tem um site para usar de fonte? Porque aparentemente o usuário não vai ter que digitar "https:// ..." só vai passar a string como parâmetro para alguma url, qual é? Porque posso responder a pergunta mas se der a URL na qual a string vai ser passada como parâmetro para o mesmo, fica mais fácil porque aí você pode testar e ver funcionando.

Comment: Bom, queria que ao pesquisar uma palavra a pessoa fosse direcionada para um dicionário. Pode ser o https://www.dicio.com.br/.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez o codigo abaixo seja o que você está tentando implementar:

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <label for="dadopesquisado">Digite aqui:</label>
    <input type="text" id="dadopesquisado" name="texto"><br><br>
    <button>Pesquisar</button>
  </form>

  <script>
    //Cria uma variavel que aponta para o botão
    const button = document.querySelector("button");

    //Adiciona um evento toda vez que o botão for clicado
    button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

      //Previne que o corportamento padrão de reiniciar a pagina aconteça
      e.preventDefault();

      //Pega o texto escrito no input
      const dataToUrl = document.querySelector("#dadopesquisado").value;

      //Abre a nova guia no endereço base + texto do input
      window.open("https://www.dicio.com.br/" + dataToUrl);
    })
  </script>
</body>
```

**Explicação**: Você é novo no frontend então precisa aprender algumas coisas importantes. HTML não é codigo, para programar em paginas web nós precisamos usar o JavaScript. Essa linguagem está condida dentro da tag `script` no trecho de HTML que enviei acima.